# can checked exceptions, if thrown by system, be caught by the default handler?

Tags: java

Also,
does the default handler catches an exception thrown by us? If yes, then does it depend on whether the exception is checked or not?

Answer (score 2):

Any `Throwable` can be caught. But subclasses of `Error` are not intended to be caught by user application code. They still can be caught, but some errors may even leave application in bad state (`OutOfMemoryError` for example).

Comment: Hmmmm - not sure about that. depends on the "user application code". what if it's a remote logger service and it runs out of disk - maybe it could clear some space by deleting old log files and retrying

Comment: @Bohemian I refer to Java Language Specification http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/exceptions.doc.html `The class Error and its subclasses are exceptions from which ordinary programs are not ordinarily expected to recover.` It does not mean that there are no cases when you want to catch them. In your specific example what error do you refer to?

Answer (score 0):

A catch block will catch any sub-type of the declared Throwable type.  For example `catch (Exception ex) {}` will handle any Exception that is thrown in the try block, as even RuntimeException (un-checked) is a child.

Note that this will not catch instances of Error, since they are not a sub-class of exception.  If you really want a catch all, you can use something like `catch (Throwable th)`.  This is not advisable, since Error's, are usually an indication of a problem that the application cannot easily recover from by itself.

Answer (score 0):

There's a little-known fact about checked/unchecked exceptions: The distinction exists **only** at compile time.

If, by some ugly trick, you manage to throw a checked exception at a place where it isn't declared to be thrown, then it will be handled just like an unchecked exception (i.e. it will will fall through as many stack frames as necessary to reach the nearest matching catch block). And yes, such tricks exist.

And if by default handle your mean the [Thread default uncaught exception handler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) (or the [per-thread uncaught exception handler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29)), then yes: they will handle both checked and unchecked exceptions that are not handled by catching them "normally".